# nginx and custom Jar in a docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to have a custom java application and nginx to run in the same docker container. The nginx acts as a reverse proxy here and redirects requests to the java application. so

outside world -> { nginx -> application } (docker).

How do I set this up?

Comment: Why do you need a proxy in the container?

Comment: How does your Java application looks like? Is it a web service? How would you launch it on your local machine?

Comment: it is a rest application, I want to have SSH with it hence the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

First I would separate the proxy from the java executable, as @jonrsharpe suggested. Just use an official nginx image for that, in another container.

Then writing the Dockerfile is pretty straightforward:

- choose a base image (java official image is probably your best choice)
- install dependencies and copy the artefact to the container
- expose the port(s) your jar is going to use
- have the Entrypoint executing your jar with the relevant options, or use something like supervisord

EDIT:

If you need to package both applications in the same container, as you mention, using supervisord as an entrypoint is almost mandatory.

Docker containers exit once the process with PID 1 dies/exits. You cannot have both java and nginx with PID 1, so you risk having a working proxy with no jar running or a jar running without proxy. 
Here is where supervisord comes handy: you can add both application to it and have the container exit as soon as one of the apps terminates.

Comment: I wanted to have the Nginx with the java application because there are other containers running in the server and I am only allowed to have a single container.